# fancybox input inside of <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

This example shows what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Dqjvy/

I would like it to work so that when you click the input to delete the file, this works without loading fancybox.

**How can I stop fancybox from loading when you click the input? This is also preventing the form from submitting because fancybox is loaded?**

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="fancybox" href="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6048/6370091853_fa920568e4_b.jpg" title="Tree and Bench, Newlands Corner (craig.denford)">
    <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6048/6370091853_fa920568e4_m.jpg" alt="">
    <input type="button" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?');" value="Delete" name="delete_file" />
</a>

<a class="fancybox" rel="fancybox" href="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6032/6370797521_74a61aec56_b.jpg" title="Brighton West Pier (George-Edwards)">
    <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6032/6370797521_74a61aec56_m.jpg" alt="">
    <input type="button" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?');" value="Delete" name="delete_file" />
</a>

<a class="fancybox" rel="fancybox" href="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6182/6059490424_451d8d75b8_b.jpg" title="Romantic sunset.  EXPLORE (Grbavica)">
    <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6182/6059490424_451d8d75b8_m.jpg" alt="">
    <input type="button" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?');" value="Delete" name="delete_file" />
</a>

<a class="fancybox" rel="fancybox" href="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6106/6347065961_bb73745e70_b.jpg" title="Fog (giulio bassi q°ן°p)">
    <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6106/6347065961_bb73745e70_m.jpg" alt="">
    <input type="button" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?');" value="Delete" name="delete_file" />
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();

/*$('.fancybox').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).fancybox();
});*/
```

Comment: I suggest to simply move `input` outside `a` so that fancybox is not triggered when you click the button (maybe create a wrapper div for each image). You can use CSS to place the button properly. See http://jsfiddle.net/Dqjvy/3/

Comment: I dont want to add the extra mark up and it's easier to absolute position the delete button over the top of the image if its inside the `a`.

Comment: Is there no way to do something like this: `.fancybox:not(input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `onClick`-attributes of the buttons with a `class`-attribute, and add this `click`-handler in your js:

HTML:

```
<input class="delete" type="button" value="Delete" name="delete_file" />
```

JS:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?')) {
        // TODO: delete file
        alert('deleted');
    }    
    return false;
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dqjvy/4/).

Answer (score 1):

To prevent clicking the Delete button from activating the fancybox, use something like this:

```
$('input[name="delete_file"]').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation()
});
```

`stopPropagation` will prevent that event from bubbling up the DOM to the Fancybox element.  `preventDefault` would just prevent the default action of clicking the button.